# Passing a big texture to a GLSL shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3, opengl-4

I need to pass two textures of 65536x1024 pixels each to the shader program. I can't do this via the standard `glTexImage2D()` method because there is a limitation on the OpenGL side on the height and width of the textures (this value is stored to the `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` constant). I was considering splitting each texture into subtextures using `glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, ...)`, but as I understand it can be difficult with that too. Is there any way to pass these textures to a shader?

Comment: "but as I understand it can be difficult with that too" -- can you elaborate? What did you try, and why is it difficult? There is simply no way to create a 2d texture larger than the implementation limit (that's what 'limit' means). Sparse virtual textures can have larger limits, but they aren't in core and that size isn't guaranteed to be supported either. You can pack your data into an SSBO (minimum supported size is 128MB), but then packing in a texture array like you propose or splitting the tiles into a square 2d texture would work just as well.

Comment: I'd rather look at why you need a texture that big, and rewrite your shader so it would need only a small portion of the texture. It's rather common to process large images in tiles.

Comment: 65536x1024 seems like it should be in range of modern graphics cards that have many gigabytes of memory. Note that the constant `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` is *not* the max texture size, it is a number that means "please tell me the max texture size". To get the max texture size you should call `glGetIntegerv` and say that GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is the thing you want to get.

Comment: @user253751 texture size limit is imposed by the texture filtering unit more so than by the available memory. As of today 16384 is the most widely supported limit, and it appears that no GPU supports texture bigger than 32768 in size. See https://opengl.gpuinfo.org/displaycapability.php?name=GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE